# How to get parent object name from JSchema/ Map JsonObjects to new parent

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a scenario where I read the data from multiple json files and map them to certain Json format.

```
e.g. file1, file2, file 3
```

jsonoutput:

```
 {
"parentfile1":"file1content",
"parentfile2":"file2content",
"parentfile3" : "file3content" and so on. 
 }
```

I am trying to map the input from the file reading directly to the valid json format to avoid reading all the files in one jsonObj, mapping it into one Object(class) and adding each parameter in the new object to create the jsonoutput.

I'd also like to handle shared mutable state while merging these json contents so I am using a lock(obj), the method that does this mapping is an async method.

I am using a JSchema to generate the schema of expected json format, :

1. check if the object in this schema contains the key(in the file), (not sure if this is possible??)
2. get it's parent name from the schema and add the parent name with the value(file content jsonobject) in the one JsonObject and
3. finally Deserialize the JSonObject in 2 to the expected file output.

Not sure if this is the best approach. Are there any other suggestion/ best practices to resolve this scenario?

Comment: Could you please share with us the code that implements the described algorithm / solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out one way to do this.

1. Generate the schema using JSchema
2. Get the properties of this schema -> Returns IDictionary with string as key-> property name and JSchema as value(child parameters/properties of the key)
3. Loop through the dictionary and get properties.value of the JSchema in 2
4. Loop through the List returned in 3-> List of keys
5. Add parent key as value and child key as key in the dictionary.

Now when adding the obj(file content) in the parent JObject, merge newJObject(parentkey, child object)